# Django Rest Framework Serializer do not want to accept returned list, and returns AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So I'm trying to aggregate a list of colors and return the queryset to the serializer, the serialzier, however, does not seem to accept this for some reason.

When running the the commands in shell i get:

```
>>> from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg
>>> from inventory.models import Product
>>> products = Product.objects.filter(category__parent__name__iexact='fliser').distinct().aggregate(colors_field=ArrayAgg('colors__name'))
>>> print(products)
{'colors_field': ['Beige', 'Grå', 'Hvit', 'Sort', 'Beige', 'Gul', 'Rød']}
```

Which is the expected result.

The serializer is structured like this:

```
class ProductFiltersByCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer to display available filters for a product lust 
    """

    colors = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['colors']
```

The viewset looks like this:

```
class ProductFiltersByCategory(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    This viewset takes the category parameter from the url and returns related product filters
    """

    serializer_class = ProductFiltersByCategorySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = self.kwargs['category']
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(category__parent__name__iexact=category).distinct().aggregate(colors_field=ArrayAgg('colors__name'))
        return queryset
```

And the relevant part of the model looks like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    ...
    colors = models.ManyToManyField(
        ProductColor,
        related_name='product_color'
    )
    ...
```

The error when trying to access the endpoint is `'str' object has no attribute 'colors'`.

Wished output:

```
[
    {
        "colors": [
            "Red",
            "Orange",
        ],
    },
]
```

Comment: how do you passing the data into the serializers? Show us the code.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu extending the ListAPIView usually does the heavy lifting, and specifying the `serializer_class = ProductFiltersByCategorySerializer` should be enough. Trying to do `serializer = ProductFiltersByCategorySerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)` in the get_queryset method returns the same error.

Comment: Your **`get_queryset()`** method returns a ***`dict`*** object. First, it shouldn't be a `dict` second, it should be a ***list like object***

Comment: How would i go about doing this? Could you please give me an example? I've added the wished output to the post. Sorry, quite new to python/django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a ***`ListAPIView`*** class here, Use **`APIView`** as

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class MyAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = kwargs['category']
        agg_result = Product.objects.filter(
            category__parent__name__iexact=category
        ).distinct().aggregate(colors_field=ArrayAgg('colors__name'))
        return Response(agg_result)
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove duplicate fields? As of now if a value is registered on both instances, two of the same string will show up: `{ "result": [ "Beige", "Red", "Yellow", "Beige", "White", "Gray", "Black" ] }`.

Comment: idk, better you as a new question.

Comment: Found it out, you can simply add the `distinct=True` in the ArrayAgg method. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductColorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductColor
        fields = '__all__'

class ProductFiltersByCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer to display available filters for a product lust 
    """

    product_color = ProductColorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['product_color']
```

Comment: I don't think this setup will generate the *required output*

Comment: it will not, coz, the serializer is receiving a ***dict*** object, not a ***`QerySet`***